# Error when calling method guestsCanModify()

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following code in a script:

```
var createdEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options);

createdEvent.guestsCanModify(true);
```

When I call the "guestsCanModify()" method, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find method guestsCanModify(boolean)
```

I have the following scopes enabled for the script:

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
"https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
```

Am I using this method incorrectly? [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#guestscanmodify) seems vague to me.

Comment: That's a getter method only, and--per documentation you show--takes no parameters. The setter method is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setGuestsCanModify(Boolean)

Comment: You're right. I saw your answer after I figured it out. Feel free to submit this as an answer and i'll make it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong method. The correct method is "setGuestsCanModify()".

[Documentation here...](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setguestscanmodifyguestscanmodify)